# Where's My Answer?

Tags: support, bounty

Last night I wrote an answer to a question that had a 300 Bounty on it for five more days. The person said, "I still want a satisfactory answer." Tonight I can no longer find the Bounty or the Question. Nor can I find my answer or a record on my profile of the activity. Where is my answer? What happened to it?

I forget the exact wording of the question; it was something about why one uses the indefinite article when talking about the wind.

The description of the question provided three examples, two of which I chose to write about, as follows:

1. There's a wind blowing through here tonight.
2. was a definition of wind; I skipped it.
3. Open the doors so I can get a breeze.

I think I wrote a good informative answer. It was different from what anyone else had posted; I understood they wanted a different approach. If it did not meet the person's "satisfaction," surely it was not so bad that it would be deleted without a sign. Where is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is [your answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/272873/why-do-we-use-the-indefinite-article-a-with-the-nouns-wind-breeze/273409#273409). Simply go to [your main site activity page or answer list, make sure your posts are sorted in order of time posted](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/110641/sarah-bowman) and voila.

The bounty has been awarded, unfortunately. And that is why you can't find the question on the bountied list any more.